# Running `at` commands with macOS Shortcuts

Tags: macos, at

I have a shortcut that I want to run in x minutes. I can run the shortcut from the command line as follows:

`shortcuts run "turn lights off"`

When I try to schedule it using `at` however, like this:

`echo "shortcuts run \"turn lights off\"" | at now + 1 minute`

I get the following error (as shown in mail):

`Error: Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.`

Is there a workaround this issue? How can I schedule shortcuts using `at`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. You can circumvent the issue by using `at` with a more privileged application such as `Automator`.

`echo "automator ./Lights.workflow" | at now + 1 minute`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post your solution! By the way, although macOS is on topic here since it is a *nix system, for this sort of question that is very macOS-specific and not really about the UNIX side of things, you would probably have better luck getting an answer on our sister site: [apple.se].

Comment: I was unaware of that site – thank you for letting me know! @terdon